# How to get related records across a join table in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

In my Rails application I have `people` which can have many `projects` and vice versa:

```
# app/models/person.rb
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :people_projects
  has_many :projects, :through => :people_projects
end

# app/models/people_project.rb
class PeopleProject < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :project 
end

# app/models/project.rb
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :people_projects
  has_many :people, :through => :people_projects

  def self.search(person_id)
    if person_id
      where("person_id = ?", person_id) # not working because no person_id column in projects table
    else
      scoped
    end
  end
end
```

How can I filter the projects by `person_id` in the `index` view of my `ProjectsController`, e.g. by using a URL like this: `http://localhost:3000/projects?person_id=164`

I can't get my head around this. Please help! Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your association definition is not complete for `Person` and `Project` models.  You also need `has_many :people_projects` defined.

```
# app/models/person.rb
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :people_projects # <-- This line
  has_many :projects, :through => :people_projects
end

# app/models/project.rb
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :people_projects # <-- This line
  has_many :people, :through => :people_projects
end

# app/models/people_project.rb
# This is defined correctly
class PeopleProject < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :project
end
```

Please reference [`The has_many :through Association`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) for further details.

With this definition, you will be able to get all the projects of the current user using `current_user.projects`, just like you've already done in your `ProjectsController#index`.

**Update:**

You could use either `joins` or `includes` in your `search` method and apply the `where` condition.  Something like follows:

```
# app/models/project.rb
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :people_projects
  has_many :people, :through => :people_projects

  def self.search(person_id)
    if person_id
      includes([:people_projects, :people]).where("people.id = ?", person_id) 
    else
      scoped
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your help. My association definition was correct. I simply forgot to include the two lines in my OP. Sorry about that. I changed my question accordingly.

Comment: @Tintin81, please see the update above.  Have a look at the like you've commented "doesn't work".

Comment: OK, thanks. I tried your suggestions but I get this error: `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: people.person_id`

Comment: @Tintin81, apologies for mis-typing the column name.  It should be `where("people.id"...` not `where("people.person_id...` as shown in the update.

Comment: `SQLite3::SQLException: ambiguous column name: created_at: SELECT  DISTINCT "projects".id FROM "projects" LEFT OUTER JOIN "invoices" ON "invoices"."project_id" = "projects"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "people_projects" ON "people_projects"."project_id" = "projects"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "people_projects" "people_projects_projects_join" ON "people_projects_projects_join"."project_id" = "projects"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "people" ON "people"."id" = "people_projects_projects_join"."person_id" WHERE "projects"."user_id" = 39 AND (people.id = '176') ORDER BY created_at desc LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0`

Comment: The reason for that error is your `order by` clause.  You need to specify the table whose `created_at` you are after.  You could append the following to your AR query `.order('projects.id desc')`

Comment: Yeeha, that did the trick! Thanks so much for your help. Without you I would have been lost. Will mark this answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

You will not have a person_id in the projects table because its a has_many<>has_many relationship.

Simply @person.projects will perform a join btw person_projects & projects tables and returns the appropriate projects.

*I assume,current_user returns a Person object.*

Also, complete your Model definitions. Each of them should list their relation to PeopleProjects

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :people_projects
  has_many :projects, :through => :people_projects
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :people_projects
  has_many :people, :through => :people_projects
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I realised I made a mistake in my original post and corrected it above.